# OAuth2 Access Token in Java EE Applications

Tags: jakarta-ee, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to find a way to use OAuth2 Access Token authentication in a Java Enterprise application. So far, the only examples I've found are relevant to Spring Boot.
For example, Spring Boot applications are able to define properties to access a Keycloak server and specify realm and client:

```
keycloak.realm=spring-boot-quickstart
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth
keycloak.ssl-required=external
keycloak.resource=app-authz-rest-employee
keycloak.bearer-only=true
keycloak.credentials.secret=secret
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].authRoles[0]=user
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].name=protected
keycloak.securityConstraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/*
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.enforcement-mode=ENFORCING
keycloak.policy-enforcer-config.claimInformationPointConfig.claims[http.uri]={request.relativePath}
```

Is there an equivalent configuration you can use for a Java Enterprise Application? Within the web.xml it seems you can only specify KEYCLOAK as auth-method:

```
 <auth-method>KEYCLOAK</auth-method>
```

but that simply redirects to keycloak login challenge. I'd like rather to use Tokens. Maybe System Properties or other ways?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are [official examples](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts) of java ee sample applications secured by Keycloak

Comment: Thanks, I was indeed pointing at the official examples. I'd need an equivalent of https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-authz-rest-employee (which uses SpringBoot) for JEE. I've seen the available examples (f.e. https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-jee-jsp) but they send me to the login page. I'd rather use token authentication.